# What does "git diff timewarp" do?

Tags: git

I accidentally entered "git diff timewarp" on my repo, and it listed a lot of changes. I was wondering what is it doing exactly? These are differences from now to when?

Comment: So you have a branch called timewarp?

Comment: @MadPhysicist My thoughts exactly (but let's note it could also be a tag). Definitely not a git reserved keyword or command.

Comment: Sounds like you have a branch (or tag) called timewarp and so git is showing differences between timewarp and your working tree.

Comment: I'm just curious. How do you *accidentally* enter `git diff timewarp`? You must have chosen that word `timewarp` for a reason.

Comment: (off-topic) *(But to be honest, my real first thought was in fact "You put your hands on your hips...")*

Comment: I added timewarp through a combination of fat finger and tab-completion. ti->. But yes, it was a branch I didn't know was in the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-diff` - Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc

In your case, if you have a branch called timewrap, the changes that are listed are the one between your branch called timewrap and your working tree (files you are currently working on).

These are differences from the files you are currently working on and the one you have commited.

For more information: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: Could also be a tag